# How you setup a greenfield project

Tags: build-process, build-automation, build, continuous-integration

I'm setting yup a Greenfield (yeeea!) web application just now was wondering how other people first setup their project with regards to automated/CI build?

I generally follow this:

1. Create SVN Repository with basic layout (trunk, braches, lib, etc.)
2. Create basic solution structure (core, ui, tests)
3. Create a basic test that fails
4. Copy NAnt scripts, update and tweak, make sure the failing test breaks the build locally
5. Commit
6. Setup default debug build on CI server (TeamCity) making sure the build fails
7. Fix text
8. Commit
   9 Make sure build passes on CI
9. Done....

Comment: well, that's a very sensible way of doing it. You have answered your own question - maybe you want to post the second part as an answer so people could vote on it and you could accept it?

Comment: I would do the same (as Chris), and agree at all (with Ilya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repost from the question text:

1. Create SVN Repository with basic
   layout (trunk, braches, lib, etc.)
2. Create basic solution structure
   (core, ui, tests)
3. Create a basic
   test that fails
4. Copy NAnt scripts,
   update and tweak, make sure the
   failing test breaks the build
   locally
5. Commit
6. Setup default debug
   build on CI server (TeamCity) making
   sure the build fails
7. Fix test
8. Commit
9. Make sure build passes on CI
10. Done....

Comment: This doesn't appear to be formatted correctly - #5 has been combined with #6. Also it doesn't help that in the original question, #8 and #9 are combined and need separating out. I don't have sufficient rep to edit the posts otherwise I would!